# I merged a pull request on GitHub and I have to changed that commit's author. How?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

I'm working on a university course's task, but sadly I was in a hurry and forgot to change my public name to my real name. Now their algorithm won't be able to pair that merge with me.

Now I changed my GitHub public name on my profile.

How could I change that merge's commit's author name to my real name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the repository, run `git commit --amend --author='"Your Name" <your@email.address>'`, and then run `git push -f`. The old merge commit will be replaced with a new one with the new author information. This assumes that no other commits have been made since that merge; if this is not the case, then you'll have to merge/rebase all of them after your new merge commit.